# Laravel 5.4 many to many relationships with foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.4

i'm using  a data table with name `auct_lots_full` for my `Lot.php` model, where primary key is `lot_id`,  in order everything to work i used [Sofa/Eloquence](https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/eloquence) extension, `Mappable`. So this is my model :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Sofa\Eloquence\Eloquence;
use Sofa\Eloquence\Mappable;

class Lot extends Model
{
    use Eloquence, Mappable;

    protected $table = 'auct_lots_full';

    protected $maps =[
        'id' => 'lot_id',
    ];


    public function scopeFilter($query, QueryFilter $filters)
    {
        return $filters->apply($query);
    }

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }

}
```

But he problem is that in some cases it keeps looking for `id` column as primary key. For example in `LotsController.php`  i have this problem here :

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $lot = Lot::find($id);
        return view('lots.show')->withLot($lot);
    }
```

But i fix this problem with this solution:

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $lot = Lot::where('lot_id', $id)->first();
        return view('lots.show')->withLot($lot);
    }
```

But i understand that is just a solution for only this function...

So the same problem i have in `CommentsController.php`:

```
public function show()
    {
        $comments   = Comment::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(30);
        return view('comments.browse', compact('comments'));

    }
```

And i don't know how to fix it. Could any one explain me why is this happening? Is there a better way than use an extension? How i can fix this error in `CommentsCotroller.php` ?

This is the `Comment.php` model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

class Comment extends Model
{

    public function lot()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Lot::class);

    }

    public function User()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);

    }
}
```

Comment: share your migration file. seems like you dont have` id` column you made it `lot_id` and find method looks for id in default

Comment: @Rodrane yes , there is no id column, thats why i used Sofa/Eloquence extension. Also i didnt have any migration because the table with data i recive from third party.    And the thing is that this data base is huge and i need to set up CRON to update it every hour.  So i have to keep all the tables names and cloumns as they are

Comment: @Rodrane Unfortunately i had to leave my pc for now. But i will try it as soon as possible.

Comment: I just figured out something else you can actually change $primaryKey to your primarykey check my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So actually i find a proper way to do it with out  Sofa/Eloquence extension, using not only foreign key but also a local key in many to many relationship. So this is the new code:

so for Lot.php i did this:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Lot extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'auct_lots_full';

    protected $primaryKey = 'lot_id';

    public function scopeFilter($query, QueryFilter $filters)
    {
        return $filters->apply($query);
    }

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class,'lot_id', 'lot_id');
    }

}
```

Than i did same for the Comment.php model:

```
<?php

namespace App;


class Comment extends Model
{


    public function lot()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Lot::class, 'lot_id', 'lot_id');

    }

    public function User()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);

    }
}
```

So what we see above, in Lot.php model, function comments i pass foreignKey: 'lot_id' in `auct_lots_full` table and localKey 'lot_id' in `comments` table witch refers to the `auct_lots_full` table.  In Comment.php model wi did the same but in case instead of localKey it is ownerKey. Im a bad at explaining so i will attach some images to make sense.

Lot.php
[image]

Comment.php
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a  `primaryKey` variable in your Model file which is `id` by default.

`/**
     * The primary key for the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';`

If you override this variable in  **Lot** model file. So your primary key will be `lot_id` instead of `id` as in default. Simply add this;

```
protected $primaryKey = 'lot_id';
```

Comment: Actually i try it before i start using the Sofa/Eloquence extension and i had the same problem even in more cases all over the project :(

Comment: The problem is always with Many to Many relationships.  Even i set up a primaryKey in Lot.php, when i use a related model, it keeps looking for  id

Comment: show me your relationships. you probably didnt define your column names so it looks for `id` instead

Comment: as I said you didnt define column names on your relationships